# Output parameter from Stored Procedure only returning zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

**System background:** Coding in VBA using MS-Access 2010.  Currently working on code behind module and calling stored procedure. The stored procedure is written in SQL and run on the Ms-SQL server 2008 application where the database is stored.

**Stored Procedure:** The stored procedure's purpose is to:

- Retrieve three input parameters: WOID, SampleID and Analyte
- Join two tables: tblWoSampleTest , tblTest
- Select testID WHERE the three values match

*note:* WOID and SampleID column are in tblWoSampleTest and Analyte is in tbltest

Once the stored procedure is called, the testId is saved to a local variable ThisTestID

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestIDForAnalyte @WOID nvarchar(60), @SampleID nvarchar(60),@Analyte nvarchar(60), @TestId int OUT
AS

   SELECT @TestID = (Select TestID = t1.TestID
   FROM tblWOSampleTest t1
   JOIN tblTest t2
   ON t1.TestID=t2.TestID 
   WHERE @WOID = t1.WOID AND @SampleID = t1.SampleID AND @Analyte = t2.Analyte)

GO
```

My issue is every time I call the stored procedure, The value ThistestId was previously initialized to is returned even though I know the test Id exists and the stored procedure seemed to run correctly.  To verify it exists I took my stored procedure and simply ran:

```
Select TestID = t1.TestID
FROM tblWOSampleTest t1
JOIN tblTest t2
ON t1.TestID=t2.TestID 
WHERE @WOID = t1.WOID AND @SampleID = t1.SampleID AND @Analyte = t2.Analyte
```

and had the correct testId returned (there will only ever be one value).  I don't think there is an issue with the data type because the testid is a number not a string.  Also here is the way I call it, although I am pretty sure this method is correct.

```
ThisTestId = 5
Set Conn = New ADODB.connection


Conn.ConnectionString = "connection string"
Conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "upGetTestIDForAnalyte"

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Analyte", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, Analyte)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@WOID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, ThisWOID)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SampleID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, 1)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@testid", adDouble, adParamOutput, , ThisTestID)

cmd.Execute
Conn.Close
msgbox ThisTestId
```

In this case a 5 will be printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your your parameter is marked with OUTPUT keyword in your stored procedure

Try to specify adParamReturnValue for your output parameter

```
cmd.CreateParameter("@testid", adDouble, adParamOutput, , adParamReturnValue)
```

Then once you called the store procedure with cmd.Execute you have to read the value

```
ThisTestId = cmd.Parameters("@testid").Value
```

Comment: Is it something like this? As in do I keep the line _cmd.parameters..._
       
        `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@testid", adDouble, adParamOutput, , ThisTestID)`
        `cmd.Execute`
        `Conn.Close`
        `ThisTestID = cmd.Parameters("@testid").Value`

Comment: Yes. You need to read the Parameter value after you execute the procedure. What do you get ?

Comment: I get an error invalid use of null at line `ThisTestID = cmd.Parameters("@testid").Value`

Comment: try to set your param with : cmd.CreateParameter("@testid", adDouble, adParamOutput, , adParamReturnValue)

Comment: My issue may be that some testIds do not exist and for those I assumed I would atleast get a zero in my output parameter and be able to test with _if ThisTestId <> 0 then...procedure code_ to filter out those records that are not needed

Comment: check the OUTPUT keyword. Did you try to call the stored procedure "manually" to see if it works ?

Comment: when i manually called the procedure, for the records with testids that did not exist the column for testid would popup but no record would be in it so I thought that would result in @testId = 0, for the records with testids, the correct testid did appear, is that what you mean by manually?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56290/discussion-between-nicod-and-victoriajay).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to SQL, but where's your return?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the output parameter after command execution.

```
  ThisTestId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("@testid").Value);
```

Comment: when I try to execute yours, I get an error at _parameters_ saying sub or function not defined